# Open source equivalent of Esri story maps?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, story-map

I am currently interested in story telling with Maps. Esri offers a tool and this is a great [example](http://www.arcgis.com/apps/MapTour/index.html?appid=d4c0475e70f34063ae3cddf2c09d16e1&webmap=4023bcfb2d884acf80ff2977410acd66#) of what I am looking for.

However, I do not own ArcGIS Online because I am not an Esri user.

Do you know a story maps equivalent product written using Open Source?

Answer (score 10):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
> should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

GeoStory is a product associated with GeoNode that preforms the equivalent of Esri Story Maps.
https://mapstore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/exploring-stories/
https://docs.geonode.org/en/master/usage/other_apps/geostory/index.html

MapStory is a possibility.  It's a platform for "playable" maps of time dependant information.  I've heard it referred to as "YouTube for maps".  Not exactly the same as Esri Story Maps, but there are some similarities.

http://mapstory.org/

https://github.com/MapStory/mapstory

---

You should try [TimeMapper](http://timemapper.okfnlabs.org/) made by the OKFN (Open Knowledge Foundation).
Explore some examples like [the Major Battles in the Napoleonic Wars](http://timemapper.okfnlabs.org/rufuspollock/major-battles-napoleonic-wars) or [the  US City Bankruptcies - Spending Stories](http://timemapper.okfnlabs.org/rufuspollock/us-city-bankruptcies) to have an idea about what it does.

See also another project called [StoryMap JS](http://storymap.knightlab.com/) by the "Knight lab". It does something quite similar to ESRI or MapStory solutions.