# StoryMap : following a path not a location point

Tags: software-recommendations, linear-referencing, story-map

I am looking for a way to make a storymap with [StoryMap JS](https://storymap.knightlab.com/) (Knight Lab) or any other Opensource solution, where it can focus on a Path (a part of a waypoint), and still have the link with the text story and the next/previous step.

The solutions I have seen are  focusing on Point location, maybe I did not have a deep look.

So what I think is to adapt the Story Map JS lib get focus on path. Any one have experiences on this lib to tell me if it's hard job or not ? How to begin ?

Comment: What happened when you tried StoryMap JS?

Comment: With StoryMap JS I canot focus on a path but only on point location

Comment: It sounds like you are seeking [softwarerecs.se] for open source story maps (other than StoryMap JS) which may be able to meet your requirements.  If you have reviewed those at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77665/open-source-equivalent-of-esri-story-maps then that would be useful information to include in your question.

Comment: not really, I will edit the question to ask "how it will be possible to adapt the StoryMap JS to my needs"