# Seeking QGIS equivalent to ESRI story maps?

Tags: qgis, story-map

I am working in QGIS and would like to continue doing so, but I need to create a "story map" that is not time sequenced (as most examples are at [Open source equivalent of Esri story maps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77665/open-source-equivalent-of-esri-story-maps))

I did find a 2016 video that references a story plugin- but that no longer exists (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MGupLsU9Eg).

Is there something that I am overlooking?

Comment: What is a story map? As in "what specifications does it have", "what purpose does it serve" and "are there specific layout guidelines"?

Comment: QGIS doesn't have an exact copy of every ArcGIS feature. Often we can find a functional equivalent or workaround, but only if we know what the ArcGIS feature does. Since those of us who are most familiar with QGIS aren't necessarily familiar with all the ArcGIS features, please explain exactly what you're trying to achieve by recreating the "story map" feature.

Comment: Give a little bit more detail on why your requirements for a story map are different than the 'time sequenced' version... also check out https://storymap.knightlab.com/

Answer (score 5):

**QGIS2WEB** is most likely your best option for a 'story map'

Example:

[image]

Full information is available here
https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html

The QGIS2WEB Plugin is still actively developed
https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web