# Open Source GIS Story Maps

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, story-map

I am helping to put together a session at a conference to see how we would want to design an OS Story Map 'Recipe' i.e. what is currently out there and how we could use it. The attendees will range from end-users to developers.

My question is, are there other options out there apart from **StoryMapJS**, **MapStore's GeoStory**, **TimeMapper**, and **Leaflet Story-maps with Google Sheets**? (I have also seen StoryMap.org as well, but it looks like it is still developing.)

I would also like to understand the supporting infrastructure options as well - I know of Leaflet. Is there anything else I need to consider here. I have only ever used ESRI Story Maps.

**I really want to emphasize that I have checked the other options from the community wiki** [Open source equivalent of Esri story maps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77665/open-source-equivalent-of-esri-story-maps) and wish to know how has the development in this area changed as the last answer was in 2021, and one of the options (mapstory) does not appear to be working, I am wondering if there are any updates?

Comment: We have a Meta GIS SE FAQ on [Options when question is duplicate of one with no/inadequate/old answers?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/options-when-question-is-duplicate-of-one-with-no-inadequate-old-answers).

Comment: I cannot respond to the Wiki, nor can I do anything mentioned in the Meta GIS SE FAQ.

Comment: With a rep of 19 the first 4 of the 7 options in the FAQ should be available to you.  As a focused Q&A site, which is quite different from a discussion forum, asking for a list of software options is a poor fit.  Once you have a rep of 20+ asking a question like this would be fine for the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis).